# Cookie expiration is not working

Tags: servlets, cookies, expired-cookies

We have an existed created cookies and they don't have any expiry date, so they are using 30 minutes default time to expire. I just wanted to make them expire in 2 minutes like below with set max age.

```
Cookie sessionCookie = new Cookie("sessioncookie", "345rfhthjii");
sessionCookie.setPath("/");
sessionCookie.setSecure(true);
sessionCookie.setMaxAge(120);
response.addCookie(sessionCookie);
```

The above code does not work, So i went through the other posts which are related to this session expiration but every solution tells about date/time which needs to set in jsp pages.

Can't we do any thing in the servlet itself?

Comment: _The above code does not work_ Please explain. What did you expect to happen? What actually happened?

Comment: The above cookie should be expired in after 2 minutes but it is not expired. I am able to see my app working even after 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The method [`setMaxAge(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge(int)) sets the expiration of the cookie in seconds, so your code:

```
sessionCookie.setMaxAge(120);
```

Should correctly create a cookie that will expire after 2 minutes.

I would check to make sure that your are clearing previous cookies, because your syntax is correct and you should be experiencing the intended behavior you described.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in Firefox. The way you are storing cookies are correct and you are right. When a cookie is expired Firefox doesn't delete it immediately.

[image: Test cookie]

As you can see `test` cookie is expired but exists in cookie list in Firefox yet. **But** you can not access this cookie by Javascript and also browser doesn't send this cookie to server. You can test it by this command in servlet:

```
Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
```

Apparently this is browser policy to update cookie list.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a few years ago, but I have been searching the min time one can set to Max-age, and on my trials the browser does not store anything less than 5 minutes, maybe that's the minimum.